# Matlab warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory

Tags: matlab, hpc, mosek

I'm running an array job (`400` Matlab R2018b tasks) in the HPC of my university. After having `qsub`, the `400` tasks start by they are immediately killed.

In the .o file of each task no errors are reported but only the following warning

```
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory:
/share/apps/.../NAG/mbl6a24dnl/mex.a64
```

In case it might be useful: I call the MOSEK solver in my Matlab .m file. In particular, at the beginning of my Matlab .m file I have

```
addpath /share/apps/mosek-9.2/9.2/toolbox/r2015aom
```

Provided that I have contacted the administrator to ask about this (no reply yet), is there anything I can do can in the immediate to fix it and run my code?

Comment: The directory mbl6a24dnl is not part of a standard matlab installation. No clue what part of your code expect it to exists and who should make sure it actually exists.

Comment: Also, `mex.a64` is a strange file name for MATLAB, MEX-files on Linux have a `.mexa64` extension. You might have forgotten to compile the MEX-file for Linux, if you developed on maybe Windows and copied your code over to the cluster.

Comment: The only "unusual" thing for which my Matlab code might differ from a standard Matlab code is that I call the MOSEK solver by adding at the beginning of the .m file `addpath /share/apps/mosek-9.2/9.2/toolbox/r2015aom`

Comment: For the rest, my Matlab code perfectly runs in my PC with Matlab R2018b.